# Phonegap - saveToPhotoAlbum not working

Tags: api, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to save the photo to my gallery by using `saveToPhotoAlbum : true;` but it's not working. The image is saving in the cache of the application folder. How do I make it appear in the Gallery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function getCapture(){
            //alert("Hello");
            navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, { 
                quality : 75,
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                saveToPhotoAlbum : true});

        }

        function cameraSuccess(imageData){
            var image = document.getElementById("image");

            image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            alert("success");

        }

        function cameraError(e){
            alert("Camera Error"+e);
        }
    </script>
```